# LD Library Path

Tags: qt, shared-library

I am not sure whether my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is working.

I installed Qt5.2.1 on Ubuntu and tried to execute an application from the command line using `sudo ./App1`. ( App1 needs sudo access, hence I executed this way)

The folder having *.so files `Qt5.2.1/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator` is provided in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `bashrc` file, but I am getting the following error

```
./App1: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Quick.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I copied all the Qt so files from QtCreator to `/usr/lib`, the application worked.

Can someone help me understand the concept, why it is not able to take the library from the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, whereas it works with Qt so files in the standard `/usr/lib` path

Also, what should be done to make this work without copying the .so files to `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Your user's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will not, by default, be inherited by the sudo environment. According to the sudoers manpage (`man sudoers`):

```
 By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to be
 executed with a new, minimal environment.  On AIX (and Linux systems
 without PAM), the environment is initialized with the contents of the
 /etc/environment file.  The new environment contains the TERM, PATH,
 HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_* variables in addi‐
 tion to variables from the invoking process permitted by the env_check
 and env_keep options.  This is effectively a whitelist for environment
 variables.
```

Note that `env_keep` is unlikely to work for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the reason noted later in the section:

```
 Note that the dynamic linker on most operating systems will remove vari‐
 ables that can control dynamic linking from the environment of setuid
 executables, including sudo.  Depending on the operating system this may
 include _RLD*, DYLD_*, LD_*, LDR_*, LIBPATH, SHLIB_PATH, and others.
 These type of variables are removed from the environment before sudo even
 begins execution and, as such, it is not possible for sudo to preserve
 them.
```

You must either find a way to make your application run without sudo, or install the libraries that it needs in one of the standard library locations.

Comment: Hi steel I just tried something to address this problem. I used lddconfig and then application was invoked with sudo. It worked find without any library path issues.                                   Any comments ?